# Is there an error in POCO C++ library documentation?

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

[Here](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Process.html) is the confusing page. Search for "/bin/ps".
The line is:

```
ProcessHandle ph(launch("/bin/ps", args, &outPipe, 0, 0));
```

Shouldnt it be:

```
ProcessHandle ph(launch("/bin/ps", args, 0, &outPipe, 0));
```

?

Comment: I did, 1st argument seems to be dup2'ed into process' stdin. But I can't believe that this error survived so long - that is why I ask.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your observation is confirmed - the order of the last three args is indeed stdin, stdout, stderr, so the outPipe in the docs is erroneously getting passed as the input instead. I have no more idea than you have, how this doc error may have gone unnoticed!-)

Comment: Thanks. I think that people might just NOT read documentation. :)

Comment: ...or at least not with as much focused attention as you put into it, @Łukasz -- it does take such focus to notice that subtle error in argument ordering which you spotted!-)

Answer (score 1):

This will be fixed in 1.3.6.